# Pass an argument between sessions in Spring Security

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm working on application that allows user to perform some actions as guest. Results are stored in the session. I would like to inject data from guest session to authenticated user session. E.g.:

1. Guest user adds something to cart, etc
2. User decides to authenticate
3. After authentication cart is restored from the previous session (i.e. passed between them)

Is there a  place where I can get both old and new user session to copy attributes from one to another?

Comment: Do you control your login logic? IE. do you have a login controller?

Comment: No, authentication is done via external auth provider.

Comment: Seems like it should be solved by session fixation strategy set to "none", but it's already set to "none".

Comment: I don't know the specific Spring security way to do this, but you could create a servlet `Filter` to copy the attributes from the session into request attributes. Then Spring logs you in and when the filter returns it copies them back.

Comment: Silly me, it worked out of the box with <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="none"/>, I was cleaning session before login in my test, so old session was lost.

Comment: Disabling session fixation protection makes your app less secure. Have you tried `<session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession"/>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by using:

```
<security:session-management session-fixation-protection="none"/>
```